# Fire a POST using Mono Reactor but do not wait for response

Tags: project-reactor

I have a requirement. Fire a `POST` call but do not wait for response, as for the POST status is reflected via a different GET call later. So, how do I just fire the POST without waiting for response and proceed with next steps?

There is something like `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` but it also uses threads from the pool, so how can I just `fire and forget` and immediately proceed with next steps in the program execution.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, where you want to "fire and forget" a POST request and not wait for its response, you can achieve it by creating a "nested subscription". Here is a quick solution for you:

```java
interface YourRepository {
    Mono<String> findSomething(String arg);
}

interface YourRestClient {
    Mono<Void> sendPost(String arg);
}

class YourService {

    private final YourRestClient yourRestClient;
    private final YourRepository yourRepository;

    Mono<Void> processSomeAction(String someArg) {
        return yourRepository.findSomething(someArg)
            .doOnNext(something -> {
                yourRestClient.sendPost(something)
                    .doOnError(error -> ...) // handle possible errors 
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                    .subscribe();
            })
            .then();
    }

}
```

This approach will send the POST request asynchronously in "bounded elastic" threads and won't block the execution of the next steps. Please note that using this "fire and forget" strategy may cause some issues to go unnoticed, so use it with caution and make sure you have adequate error handling and monitoring in place.